# how to retrieve path as link in asp.net which is saved in mysql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I m saving path of images, audio and video files that path is of folder saved at server. Now I want that path as link in c# for the purpose of download.

Is there any way how to do that?

I'm not suppose to use gridview to show link.

EDIT:-

```
 ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathI, ClientFileName); 
 string serverPath=Server.MapPath(ServerFileName); 
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(serverPath); 
 dbInsert("Image",fileName,fileExt,serverPath); 
 //dbinsert stores values to database. and in database it is showing path just as
 //c:InetpubwwwRootFileUploadingpenguin.jpg and not showing 
 //'\\' though i have used datatype varchar
```

EDIT:-

```
protected void dbInsert(string fileType,string fileName,string fileExt,
      string filePath) 
{ 
    string getSQL1; 
    getSQL1 = "INSERT into tbluploadedfilesdetail (FileDownloaded,FileType, 
      FileName,FileExt,FilePath) VALUES ('false','" + fileType + "','" + 
      fileName + "','" + fileExt + "','"+filePath+"');"; 
    MySqlConnection objMyCon1 = new MySqlConnection(strProvider); 
    objMyCon1.Open(); 
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(getSQL1, objMyCon1); 
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    objMyCon1.Close(); 
    dbLoad(); 
}
```

Comment: please show one example path saved in db and let us know how do you want to show links.

Comment: ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathI, ClientFileName); string serverPath=Server.MapPath(ServerFileName); FileUpload1.SaveAs(serverPath); dbInsert("Image",fileName,fileExt,serverPath);  dbinsert stores values to database. and in database it is showing path just as c:InetpubwwwRootFileUploadingpenguin.jpg and not showing '\\' though i have used datatype varchar

Comment: will you show `dbInsert` code. May be it is doing something with the path string to strip slashes.

Comment: protected void dbInsert(string fileType,string fileName,string fileExt,string filePath)
         {
             string getSQL1;
           getSQL1 = "INSERT into tbluploadedfilesdetail (FileDownloaded,FileType,FileName,FileExt,FilePath) VALUES ('false','" + fileType + "','" + fileName + "','" + fileExt + "','"+filePath+"');";
MySqlConnection objMyCon1 = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
  objMyCon1.Open();
             MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(getSQL1, objMyCon1);
             cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             objMyCon1.Close();
             dbLoad();
         }

Comment: Please post code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Normally if you have images in folder named **images** under root folder of your site and you save path for an image named **image1.jpg** as **images/image1.jpg** you can get link as follows:
`var path="images/image1.jpg";//you get this from db
var link=Page.ResolveUrl("~/"+path);//gives /images/image1.jpg`
`~/` specified path relative to root folder of your site.</strike>

Normally I save the physical path and virtual path separately. Moreover you can get physical path from virtual path easily. You should save `FileUpload/ingpenguin.jpg` only and can get physical path easily as follows:

```
var root = Server.MapPath("/");//path to the root folder
// will return full path 
var imagePath = Server.MapPath("FileUpload/inpenguin.jpg");
```

For more informaiton you can refer to [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417074237/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121799-1.shtml)